# How to install Diaspora Project?

Tags: 11.04

Could you please tell me the steps, one by one, to reach it? It's a little bit difficult for me right now.

Comment: What is the Diaspora Project? Google yields multiple results.

Comment: https://joindiaspora.com/ Check this, please or this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-DwxOQFIu4&feature=related  Diaspora Project is an open source social network.

Comment: @JorgePinho Do you want to have this question still opened? Did you reach to an answer? Also, you can start a bounty..

Answer (score 2):

This is actually an ongoing development. Diaspora is currently in the process of being packaged up for Debian, but those packages are likely going to be copied over to our Launchpad PPA for Ubuntu users to make use of when the time is right.

Below are some useful links regarding what's going on:

- [Debian Diaspora Packaging Effort](http://wiki.debian.org/Diaspora/Packaging)
- [Diaspora Ubuntu PPA](https://launchpad.net/diaspora-ppa)

Answer (score 1):

Installation instructions that helped me can be found on the [Diaspora*-Wiki](https://wiki.diasporafoundation.org/Installation/Ubuntu/Xenial?db=mysql&mode=development#Prepare_the_system).

Official support:

- IRC channel on freenode #diaspora
- [Discourse](https://discourse.diasporafoundation.org/c/support)

Possible unofficial alternatives:

- Ask on Diaspora itself adding hashtag #Diaspora and/or #question, for example.
- Continue asking here on StackExchange.